# Get current date in a specific format

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve the current date in the following format: `21-FEB-17`.

I have the following code but it isn't the format I need. It prints out in the following format: `21-February-17.`

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy");
String today = formatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println(today);
```

Comment: I would suggest using the new Java 8 Time's methods.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html
And there you can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the "first 3 letters" of the month, you should use

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

as per the [Oracle documentation of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

That will print the month in "Camel" case (i.e., "Feb"). If you want it in all uppercase, you need to do

```
System.out.println(today.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format had and extra `M`:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String today = formatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println(today.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to help you understand better.

And to answer your question use below code.

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String today = formatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println(today.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer you asked for, but it may be the answer you want. :-) As Bojan Petkovic has already said in a comment, if there’s any way you can use Java 8, you will want to use the new `java.time` classes:

```
    final Locale myLocale = Locale.US;
    String today = LocalDate.now()
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yy", myLocale))
            .toUpperCase(myLocale);
    System.out.println(today);
```

This prints:

```
22-FEB-17
```

You will notice I explicitly use a locale object both for the formatter and for converting to uppercase. You know best which locale you want to use. You may also leave out the locale argument in both places, then the computer’s default locale will be used (so you will get different results on different computers). For a locale neutral formatting, use `Locale.ROOT` (it will be rather like `Locale.US`).